# Is it possible to use key() function in MapForce

Tags: xslt, map-force

Hi I have a situation where I really need to use the XSLT key() function with MapForce.  Is it possible?  I am using MapForce 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to use a simple filter (Menu - Insert: Filter) and then create a boolean function to match whatever criteria you need to match.

Map the node-set of the domain (input schema) to the range (output schema) by placing the filter in-between the normal mapping. Map the [parent] node of the domain to the filter's 'node/row(s)' as if it was the *match* parameter of the key definition. Map the output (the 'on-true' part of the filter) to the matching parent node of the range.

For the *use* parameter of the key, map to the 'bool' input of the filter by using any boolean function.  The boolean function can do your key match by using logic to compare the preferred node in the domain to whatever you would like to use as match criteria, and will only consider nodes that evaluate to true.  The filter then allows you to map any child nodes directly from the domain to the range that belong to the matched node-set, including other 'sub'filters.

I don't have enough rep to link an image, but here is one that will hopefully make the answer make more sense: http://home.comcast.net/~frietze/pwpimages/mapforcefilter.png

Documentation from Altova:
http://manual.altova.com/Mapforce/mapforcebasic/mfffilteringdata.htm